# what type of server is best for launching a vulnerable application on an Organization network?

Tags: web-application, appsec, webserver, server, mod-security

For a demo purpose i need to install a vulnerable application and i tried using XAMP server but it opens up many ports and not safe to use it. so please recommend a server to launch a vulnerable demo application in an sophisticated org environment.

Comment: It's hard to tell what a good answer would be, with the current amount of information given. e.g., what does the application need to do, who does it have to be accessible for, what constraints are preventing you from using a hardened configuration for XAMP, etc.?

Comment: I got an answer for this, using xamp in virtualbox. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a dedicated, separate virtual environment and not a system in your business environments.

If it's for a demo, you should use Virtualbox or similar hypervisor and run it in Host-Only network mode. Running a known-vulnerable service/system in a business environment is asking for trouble.